# Как правильно сравнить дату и время?

Tags: php, дата, время, сравнение

В общем суть задачи, нужно выводить сообщение в будни дни с 18 вечера и до 9 утра и в любое время выходного дня.

Есть две функции одна сравнивает время, другая проверяет на выходной день

```
    function WeekendCheck($date) {
        return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
    }

    function TimeCheck($date) 
    {
       $date_min = new DateTime("9:00");
       $date_max = new DateTime("18:00");
       $date_now = new DateTime($date);
       if ($date_now >= $date_min && $date_now <= $date_max) 
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    if (WeekendCheck("2017-10-07"))
    {
        print("Сообщение в выходной день");
    } else {
        if(!TimeCheck("8:00")) {
            print("Сообщение в будний день");
        }
    };
```

Этот вариант работает как надо, но есть ли варианты попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TimeCheck(){
    $now = (int) (new DateTime())->format("H");
    return $now < 9 || $now > 18;
}
function WeekendCheck(){
    $now = (int) (new DateTime())->format("w");
    return $now === 0 || $now === 6;
}
if (WeekendCheck()){
    print("Сообщение в выходной день");
} else if(TimeCheck()) {
    print("Сообщение в будний день");
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант. Только $now >= 18. И если текст одинаковый, условия проще нельзя сделать?

Comment: `w Порядковый номер дня недели от 0 (воскресенье) до 6 (суббота)`. Ну вот так, да :). Если текст одинаковый, то, конечно, можно объединить в один оператор `if(WeekendCheck() || TimeCheck()){`